# What is the difference between these two Pig data types?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Given this example:

```
describe A;
A: {ht.udf.cleanlog_log_5: (ip: chararray,property_id: int)}
```

My understanding is that A is a **bag** made of **tuples** of type `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_5`.
(correct?)

When I apply this transformation:

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN($0);
describe B;
B: {ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7::ip: chararray,ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7::property_id: int}
```

What is B?
Is it a bag with unnamed tuples?
Where each tuple has two named fields? (i.e. `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7` and `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7`)

Thank you

Comment: I am assuming it should be `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7` OR `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_5` in both the places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is almost correct. The issue is that when you use `DESCRIBE`, Pig doesn't actually explicitly mark the large "tuple" which is the entire record.

As you said, relations are bags of tuples. When you read a file, for example, the bag encompasses all the data in the file and each line of the file is a tuple. In your case, `A` is a bag of tuples. Each tuple in the bag has one element, `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_5`. This element is also a tuple, with two elements, `ip` and `property_id`.

Now, when you use `FLATTEN` on a tuple, it "promotes" the elements of that tuple to be elements of the containing tuple. So `B` is a bag of tuples. Each tuple of the bag has two elements, `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7::ip` and `ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7::property_id`.

A more correct way of `DESCRIBE`ing a relation's schema would be to show this tuple, like

```
describe A;
A: {(ht.udf.cleanlog_log_5: (ip: chararray,property_id: int))}
describe B;
B: {(ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7::ip: chararray,ht.udf.cleanlog_log_7::property_id: int)}
```

But these tuples are never named and can never be referred to, so there is no use in showing them.